# Cannot style WinJS Listview invoked items

Tags: css, listview, windows-phone-8, winjs

I am trying to change the background color of an item when it is invoked in my WinJS Listview. This is a Windows Phone 8.1 app.  I have already tried what is documented here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh850406.aspx

Nothing unusual about my ListView, pretty vanilla...

```
 <div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="itemContainer">
        <div>
            <div data-win-bind="innerText: name"></div>
            <div data-win-bind="innerText: timestamp"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listView"
   data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
   data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#itemTemplate'),
      layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout},
      selectionMode: 'single',
      tapBehavior: 'invokeOnly' }">
</div>
```